# DC replication via Kafka Connect for Apache Ignite

Tags: apache-kafka, ignite, apache-kafka-connect

We are trying to implement the replication of data between two Ignite data clusters.

For this purpose, we are using Kafka Connect.

We have followed the things mentioned in this document -> https://dzone.com/articles/linking-apache-ignite-and-apache-kafka-for-highly

Everything is working fine till we use one cache and PUT operation.

But when I use the same for REMOVED operation, in the consumer thread of the connector, I can see the CacheEvent record, but the data is not being removed from the Sink Cluster nodes.

Can someone please help with this case?

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with the Ignite Kafka integration. Try to collect all the relevant details and report to the Ignite community via the [user list](https://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html).

In the meantime, if the issue is not solved you can consider other replication options:

1. Replication via the certified [GridGain Kafka Connect integration](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/integrations/kafka/kc-ex-replication).
2. [Datacenter replication](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/data-center-replication/introduction) feature by GridGain.